# How to submit form in which ? is used instead of = on GET method

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

The form structure would be something like this:

```
<form target="site.url/search/">
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="a">
</form>
```

How do I submit it where instead of this:

https://site.url/search/keyword=a

It would end up like this:

https://site.url/search/keyword?a

---

I am thinking another approach as well where the target url would be:

https://site.url/search/keyword?

And then find a way to get the text field value but not include the text field name so it immediately attaches to the tail end of  the url, like this.

https://site.url/search/keyword?myKeyword

Is this possible?

Comment: you can't do this, `?` is query parameter, if you do so, `myKeyword` would be a query key, not a value.

Comment: Both options are impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript to prevent the form from submitting and then redirect the page.

You'll have to add an `onsubmit` event to the form and give your input field an `ID` so you can grab the value.

```
<form target="site.url/search/" onsubmit="mySubmitFunction(event)">
<input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" value="a">
</form>
```

Then in your javascript stop the normal function of the form, get the value entered in the field, and then redirect the page.

```
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
  window.location.replace("https://site.url/search/keyword?" + keyword);
}
```

Comment: yeah only that option we have to do that.

Comment: Ah yes I resorted to this. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the form entirely and mimic the redirect function on Enter key (I dont have a submit button at the moment)